# Create a new probability distribution R

Tags: r, probability, probability-density

I would like to create a new probability density function in R as follows:

P{X=x} = p

P{X=/=x} follows a Poisson distribution with some parameter lambda but normalized s.t. the sum of all probabilities equals (1-p)

How could I make R recognize this as a new probability distribution and have it create all the corresponding functions (r, d, p, q)?

Comment: Not certain I understand what you mean, since each `[rdpq]*` functions are independently written and executed. Often, new distributions are reversals from a continuous uniform distribution, and the author has to write their own `[dpq]*` functions to go along with the `r*` function.

Comment: @r2evans Okay I think I get it. I was just trying to make a new probability distribution and thought R could handle the [rdpq] by itself. How would one get a new distribution into R then?

Comment: Vice making a new one, can you just modify `rpois` to do your normalizing? Otherwise, perhaps researching "create random number uniform inverse" would provide some help. If by "get a new distribution into R" you mean "add functions to R so that I can use it elsewhere", then look into writing functions and perhaps creating packages (perhaps reading some of the hadleyverse of [packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) or [advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are essentially creating a mixture class of a Dirac distribution and discrete Poisson distribution. The `distr` package does allow symbolic manipulations of distributions and it allows definitions of `Dirac`, various `Discrete`-classed functions including `Pois`, and mixtures of same with the `UnivarMixingDistribution`-class.

```
require(distr)
 x=5;lambda=4; p=0.3
 mylist <- UnivarMixingDistribution(Pois(4), Dirac(x) ,
           mixCoeff=c(p, 1-p))
 plot(mylist)
#NULL
```

You should look at the full package documentation since it provides `[rdpq]*` methods for distributions defined this way.

[image]

Here's how to use the `p()` and `r()` methods for that function/class definition:

```
> p(mylist)(4)
[1] 0.1886511
> p(mylist)(5)
[1] 0.9355392
> p(mylist)(0:10)
 [1] 0.005494692 0.027473460 0.071430997 0.130041046 0.188651095
 [6] 0.935539186 0.966797878 0.984659989 0.993591044 0.997560401
[11] 0.999148145
> r(mylist, 10)
Error in r(mylist, 10) : unused argument (10)
> r(mylist)( 10)
 [1] 5 2 5 5 5 5 5 3 5 5
```

You may also find useful information at `?family` where a list of functions are defined for links and error structures for R models.